# How to sync different table structure in SymmetricDS?

Tags: symmetricds

How to synchronize different table structure in SymmetricDS?

Let say, I want to sync this tables:

(Server Node) Student | Id, Name

(Branch Node) Person | Id, Name, Birth Date

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an implied transform and set the source table to Student and the target table to Person.  The Id and Name columns will automatically transfer.   You could add a column transform as a child to this table transform to include a Birth Date with no source column.   Im not sure where you get the birth date but there are other column transform types such as lookup etc that might help.

Comment: SymmetricDS is also resilient in the fact that it can automatically ignore columns that are missing or are extra (as long as they are nullable or have a default value)